# A statement about positive semi-definite matrix

Tags: matrices

I heard that

> for a Hermitian or symmetric matrix, if it is positive semi-definite,
>   then all its square submatrices (not just those along diagonal) are non-negative

1. I suspect the statement is wrong.

   There can be different interpretations of "non-negative".

   If the statement meant to say "all its square submatrices (not just
   those along diagonal) have non-negative determinants", then matrix
   $[2,-1;-1,2]$ would be a positive semidefinite matrix but the square
   submatrix $[-1]$ doesn't have nonnegative determinant.

   If the statement meant to say "all its square submatrices (not just
   those along diagonal) are positive semi-definite", then matrix
   $[2,-1;-1,2]$ would still be a positive semidefinite matrix but the
   square submatrix $[-1]$ isn't positive semi-definite.

   So I wonder what the statement might actually want to mean? What is
   the closest correct statement to it?
2. Is the converse of the statement also true, i.e. "for a Hermitian or
   symmetric matrix, if all its square submatrices (not just those
   along diagonal) are non-negative, then it is positive
   semi-definite"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I think it wants to mean that for any set of indices $J\subset\{1,2,..,n\}$, the matrix $\ ( a_{jk})_{j,k\in J}\ $ is positive semi-definite.

Comment: Thanks! Is the converse true that "for a Hermitian or symmetric matrix, of $n$ by $n$, if  for any set of indices $J⊂{1,2,..,n}$, the matrix  $(a_{jk})j,k∈J $ is positive semi-definite, then the matrix is positive semi-definite"?

Comment: Added: in the condiition in my previous comment, I meant those submatrices that are not the full matrix.

Comment: Also  is it true that "for a Hermitian or symmetric matrix, of n by n, if for any set of indices $J⊂1,2,..,n$, the matrix $(a_{jk})j,k∈J$ has nonnegative determinant, if and only if the matrix is positive semi-definite"?